# OpenSSL Elliptic Curve reading private key in DER form

Tags: openssl

I have an EC private key in DER form that I want to transform to PEM form. But I cant read the DER form.

The private key is generated as:

```
openssl ecparam -param_enc named_curve -check -name "-secp384r1" -genkey -noout -out "params.pem" -outform pem
openssl pkcs8 -in "params.pem" -inform pem -topk8 -nocrypt -out "private.der" -outform der
```

If I then try to read the private key with

```
openssl ec -in private.der -inform der
```

I get the error:

```
read EC key
unable to load Key
4674530924:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong tag:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1144:
4674530924:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:717:
4674530924:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=privateKey, Type=EC_PRIVATEKEY
4674530924:error:10FFF010:elliptic curve routines:CRYPTO_internal:EC lib:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/ec/ec_asn1.c:1353:
```

If I try with:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in private.der -inform der
```

Then I get these error:

```
Error reading key
4460752492:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong tag:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1144:
4460752492:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:317:Type=X509_ALGOR
4460752492:error:0DFFF03A:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:nested asn1 error:/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-47.140.1/libressl-2.8/crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:646:Field=algor, Type=X509_SIG
```

Note that if I generate in PEM format directly:

```
openssl pkcs8 -in "params.pem" -inform pem -topk8 -nocrypt -out "private.pem" -outform pem
```

Then I have no problem reading it with:

```
openssl ec -in private.pem -inform pem
```

Comment: specify _fully_ the input format: `openssl pkcs8 -in private.der -inform der -nocrypt` (and this is not about programming, and MacOS really has LibreSSL not OpenSSL although the difference doesn't matter here)

Comment: Thanks, this also works. I was certain that I had tested with -nocrypt but I probably did it on the ec command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [man page for `openssl ec`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ec.html) sheds some light on the behavior you have observed. It mentions

> OpenSSL uses the private key format specified in 'SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography' (http://www.secg.org/). To convert an OpenSSL EC private key into the PKCS#8 private key format use the pkcs8 command.

You have used the commands to generate the PKCS#8 formatted keys but subsequently tried to use the `openssl ec` tool to read them in as the other (SEC 1) format. That is expected to fail. You should use [the `openssl pkey` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkey.html) for that instead:

```
$ openssl pkey -inform DER -in private.der 
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIG2AgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAiBIGeMIGbAgEBBDCY6UCzQ6eDGo83UyWc
rCQw4caWF9Ttz/crt0/ba1AwQbJqSIHZIP+7f9HZdSY/VsOhZANiAATYTEaeRFGN
R6/LlKtEDzPHqIK6xr4Qp4Iz+t/ZXLccL3gdedDmtuSUbPiwj8/QI+gpW9MslkYf
c/Rm6OQpn4P1IagR98B+qSNW47olBlzzLP/k/Zqz71x9mgyQrBhYZWw=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, `openssl ec` apparently succeeds to read a PEM encoded PKCS#8 key, as you  mentioned under *Then I have no problem reading it with...*. The question/surprise is not so much: "why is `openssl ec` not able to read the private key as DER?", but: "why is `openssl ec` able to read the private key as PEM?`. The answer to that is in the same man page:

> The PEM form is the default format: it consists of the DER format base64 encoded with additional header and footer lines. In the case of a private key PKCS#8 format is also accepted.

---

If you want to dig deeper, you can follow the source code, starting in [`apps/ec.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/90cebd1b216e0a160fcfd8e0eddca47dad47c183/apps/ec.c#L177-L197). It shows the use of `d2i_ECPrivateKey_bio()` to read the key in the case of DER and `PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey()` in the case of PEM. The former is a simple deserialization function. The latter contains more intelligence though, as explained in [the manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PEM_write_PrivateKey.html) says:

> The read functions transparently handle traditional and PKCS#8 format encrypted and unencrypted keys.

"Traditional" here refers to that SEC 1 format mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank You for the nice explanation!